# Assigning group number based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

We have a table like the following

[image]

and we want to write a query with generated Group ID(based on the following)

If a country has more than 1 item with the same category then that [country, category] group records should be assigned with a unique group ID,

so for the above table we need to write a single query **(no stored proc or function)** which will return the result like below.

[image]

We tried the query and its look like very complicated and not readable.

So we are looking for a better query to achieve the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Using SQL Server? Tagged with two different dbs.

Comment: Kinda looks like Access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, you can do this by adding `OVER()` to a `COUNT()` and using `CASE` statements with `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Country,Category) CT
                      ,CASE WHEN Category IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Country) END Rank_
              FROM Table1)
SELECT Country
      ,State
      ,Category
      ,CASE WHEN CT > 1 AND Rank_ IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_Rank() OVER(ORDER BY Rank_ DESC) END AS Group_
FROM cte
ORDER BY Country DESC,State
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0198/10/0)

Only if you care about it being numbered from 1-n do you need more than one `DENSE_RANK()`.

Comment: Perfect for the solution am  looking for, still its big sql for my case. But this one is more readable and easy to maintain. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL you can use the following:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f381/7/0

```
select t.country, t.state, t.category, v.grp
  from (select x.*, @r := @r + 1 as grp
          from (select country, category
                  from tbl
                 where category is not null
                 group by country, category
                having count(*) > 1
                 order by category, state, country) x
         cross join (select @r := 0) r) v
 right join tbl t
    on v.country = t.country
   and v.category = t.category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL Server as:

```
select t.*, cs.groupnum
from table t left outer join
     (select country, category, count(*) as cnt,
             dense_rank() over (order by country, category) as groupnum 
      from table t
      group by country, category
      having count(*) > 1
     ) cs
     on t.country = cs.country and t.category = cs.category;
```

In MySQL, you can do a variant on this using variables instead of `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE #TEST

GO

CREATE TABLE #Test(
    Country NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[State] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,Category NVARCHAR(100)
    ,GroupID INT);

GO

INSERT INTO #Test 
    (Country, State, Category)
VALUES
    ('US','AZ','G1'),
    ('US','AL','G1'),
    ('US','NY',null),
    ('UK','TN','G1'),
    ('UK','MH','G1'),
    ('UK','AP','G3'),
    ('CA','MI',null),
    ('CA','CA',null);


UPDATE
    T2
SET
    T2.GroupID = T.RANKED_ID
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 'Count'
             ,Country
             ,Category
             ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Country DESC) AS Ranked_ID
      FROM #Test
      WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Country, Category
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) AS T
     JOIN #Test T2
     ON T.Category = T2.Category
     AND T.Country = T2.Country


SELECT *
FROM #TEST
```