# seqentially number groups based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need some help with my R code - I've been trying to get it to work for ages and i'm totally stuck.

I have a large dataset (~40000 rows) and I need to assign group IDs to a new column based on a condition of another column. So if df$flow.type==1 then then that [SITENAME, SAMPLING.YEAR, cluster] group should be assigned with a unique group ID. This is an example:

[image]

This is a similar question but for SQL: [Assigning group number based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577742/assigning-group-number-based-on-condition). I need a way to do this in R - sorry I am a novice at if_else and loops. The below code is the best I could come up with but it isn't working. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance for your help

```
if(flow.type.test=="0"){
  event.samp.num.test <- "1000"
} else (flow.type.test=="1"){
  event.samp.num.test <- Sample_dat %>% group_by(SITENAME, SAMPLING.YEAR, cluster) %>% tally()}
```

Note the group ID '1000' is just a random impossible number for this dataset - it will be used to subset the data later on.

My subset df looks like this:

```
>  str(dummydat)
'data.frame':   68 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ SITENAME     : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SAMPLING.YEAR: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ DATE         : Date, format: "2017-10-17" "2017-10-17" "2017-10-22" "2017-11-28" ...
 $ TIME         : chr  "10:45" "15:00" "15:20" "20:59" ...
 $ flow.type    : int  1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ cluster      : int  1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

Sorry I tried dput but the output is horrendous. I have subset 40 rows of the subset data below as an example, I hope this is okay.

```
  > head(dummydat, n=40)
   SITENAME SAMPLING.YEAR       DATE  TIME flow.type cluster
1         A             3 2017-10-17 10:45         1       1
2         A             3 2017-10-17 15:00         1       1
3         A             3 2017-10-22 15:20         0       2
4         A             3 2017-11-28 20:59         0       3
5         A             3 2017-12-05 18:15         1       4
6         A             3 2017-12-06  8:25         1       4
7         A             3 2017-12-10 10:05         0       5
8         A             3 2017-12-15 15:12         0       6
9         A             3 2017-12-19 17:40         0       7
10        A             4 2018-12-09 18:10         1       8
11        A             4 2018-12-16 10:35         0       9
12        A             4 2018-12-26  6:47         0      10
13        A             4 2019-01-01 14:25         0      11
14        A             4 2019-01-05 16:40         0      12
15        A             4 2019-01-12  7:42         0      13
16        A             4 2019-01-20 16:15         0      14
17        A             4 2019-01-28 10:41         0      15
18        A             4 2019-02-03 16:30         1      16
19        A             4 2019-02-04 17:14         1      16
20        B             1 2015-12-24  6:21         1      16
21        B             1 2015-12-29 17:41         1      17
22        B             1 2015-12-29 23:33         1      17
23        B             1 2015-12-30  5:17         1      17
24        B             1 2015-12-30 17:23         1      17
25        B             1 2015-12-31  5:29         1      17
26        B             1 2015-12-31 11:35         1      17
27        B             1 2015-12-31 23:40         1      17
28        B             1 2016-02-09 10:53         0      18
29        B             1 2016-03-03 15:23         1      19
30        B             1 2016-03-03 17:37         1      19
31        B             1 2016-03-03 21:33         1      19
32        B             1 2016-03-04  3:17         1      19
33        B             2 2017-01-07 13:16         1      20
34        B             2 2017-01-07 22:24         1      20
35        B             2 2017-01-08  6:34         1      20
36        B             2 2017-01-08 11:42         1      20
37        B             2 2017-01-08 20:50         1      20
38        B             2 2017-01-31 11:39         1      21
39        B             2 2017-01-31 16:45         1      21
40        B             2 2017-01-31 22:53         1      21
```

Comment: For `row.names` 20 and 21 in the example above, `group.ID` is 1 and 2 - why are they not in the same group, with same `SITENAME` and `SAMPLING.YEAR`?

Comment: Oh wow good pick up! I forgot it is grouped by a 3rd variable (df$cluster) which I accidentally edited out of the example data. The cluster variable groups rows that are <=1.5 days apart. You can see there is about 5 days between data points in the 20th and 21st rows. I can’t edit my question just now but I’ll get back to it as soon as I can to include this info.

Comment: question is now edited to include the variable df$cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach with `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(df, df %>%
  filter(flow.type == 1) %>%
  group_by(SITENAME, SAMPLING.YEAR) %>%
  mutate(group.ID = cumsum(cluster != lag(cluster, default = first(cluster))) + 1)) %>%
  mutate(group.ID = replace_na(group.ID, 1000))
```

First, `filter` rows that have `flow.type` of 1. Then, `group_by` both `SITENAME` and `SAMPLING.YEAR` to count groups within those same characteristics. Next, use `cumsum` for cumulative sum of when `cluster` value changes - this will be the group number. This will be merged back with original data (`left_join`). To have those with `flow.type` 0 become 1000 for `group.ID`, you can use `replace_na`.

**Output**

```
   SITENAME SAMPLING.YEAR       DATE  TIME flow.type cluster group.ID
1         A             3 2017-10-17 10:45         1       1        1
2         A             3 2017-10-17 15:00         1       1        1
3         A             3 2017-10-22 15:20         0       2     1000
4         A             3 2017-11-28 20:59         0       3     1000
5         A             3 2017-12-05 18:15         1       4        2
6         A             3 2017-12-06  8:25         1       4        2
7         A             3 2017-12-10 10:05         0       5     1000
8         A             3 2017-12-15 15:12         0       6     1000
9         A             3 2017-12-19 17:40         0       7     1000
10        A             4 2018-12-09 18:10         1       8        1
11        A             4 2018-12-16 10:35         0       9     1000
12        A             4 2018-12-26  6:47         0      10     1000
13        A             4 2019-01-01 14:25         0      11     1000
14        A             4 2019-01-05 16:40         0      12     1000
15        A             4 2019-01-12  7:42         0      13     1000
16        A             4 2019-01-20 16:15         0      14     1000
17        A             4 2019-01-28 10:41         0      15     1000
18        A             4 2019-02-03 16:30         1      16        2
19        A             4 2019-02-04 17:14         1      16        2
20        B             1 2015-12-24  6:21         1      16        1
21        B             1 2015-12-29 17:41         1      17        2
22        B             1 2015-12-29 23:33         1      17        2
23        B             1 2015-12-30  5:17         1      17        2
24        B             1 2015-12-30 17:23         1      17        2
25        B             1 2015-12-31  5:29         1      17        2
26        B             1 2015-12-31 11:35         1      17        2
27        B             1 2015-12-31 23:40         1      17        2
28        B             1 2016-02-09 10:53         0      18     1000
29        B             1 2016-03-03 15:23         1      19        3
30        B             1 2016-03-03 17:37         1      19        3
31        B             1 2016-03-03 21:33         1      19        3
32        B             1 2016-03-04  3:17         1      19        3
33        B             2 2017-01-07 13:16         1      20        1
34        B             2 2017-01-07 22:24         1      20        1
35        B             2 2017-01-08  6:34         1      20        1
36        B             2 2017-01-08 11:42         1      20        1
37        B             2 2017-01-08 20:50         1      20        1
38        B             2 2017-01-31 11:39         1      21        2
39        B             2 2017-01-31 16:45         1      21        2
40        B             2 2017-01-31 22:53         1      21        2
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben! I’ll try this in the morning and let you know. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ben you are a genius! This worked, thank you so much! Are there any resources you would recommend that I can use to learn more about tidyverse and pipes? I've looked up heaps of online examples (SO, tutorials) but I just cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Glad to hear! Maybe take a look at [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) or some of the Data Camp lessons for more on `tidyverse`. I really use `tidyverse` a lot and recommend spending time becoming familiar with common data manipulation functions. Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Ben I'm hoping you can help with a small error I just found (to do with the same data/code). If you look at row 20 it has been allocated the same cluster as rows 19 and 18, when in fact the latter two rows belong to a different SITENAME. I need to group this function by SITENAME somehow, but nothing I've tried seems to work. here is my code to create this variable:

Comment: Sample_dat <- data.frame(Sample_dat, cluster = cumsum(c(1L, diff(Sample_dat$DATEdigit) > 1.5)))

Comment: df$DATEdigit is simply the date as numeric

Comment: There's a lot of ways to deal with something like this...one easy/quick way is to add an "offset" for each `SITENAME`...such as by `df$offset <- as.numeric(factor(df$SITENAME))` ... then just add the offset when determining `cluster`: `data.frame(df, cluster = df$offset + cumsum(c(0L, diff(...` etc...

Comment: I wanted to message you directly but I don't know how on SO. I can see you are a researcher and am wondering if we can chat re the possibility of professional code QC and paper review. My team needs a good independent reviewer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure you can do better than me for professional work. SO does not support individual private contact. Those who have SO profiles with contact info may be open to such work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[
  , group.ID := 1000
][
  flow.type == 1, group.ID := copy(.SD)[, grp := .GRP, by = cluster]$grp, 
  by = .(SITENAME, SAMPLING.YEAR)
]
```

Output

```
 > df[]
    SITENAME SAMPLING.YEAR       DATE     TIME flow.type cluster group.ID
 1:        A             3 2017-10-17 10:45:00         1       1        1
 2:        A             3 2017-10-17 15:00:00         1       1        1
 3:        A             3 2017-10-22 15:20:00         0       2     1000
 4:        A             3 2017-11-28 20:59:00         0       3     1000
 5:        A             3 2017-12-05 18:15:00         1       4        2
 6:        A             3 2017-12-06 08:25:00         1       4        2
 7:        A             3 2017-12-10 10:05:00         0       5     1000
 8:        A             3 2017-12-15 15:12:00         0       6     1000
 9:        A             3 2017-12-19 17:40:00         0       7     1000
10:        A             4 2018-12-09 18:10:00         1       8        1
11:        A             4 2018-12-16 10:35:00         0       9     1000
12:        A             4 2018-12-26 06:47:00         0      10     1000
13:        A             4 2019-01-01 14:25:00         0      11     1000
14:        A             4 2019-01-05 16:40:00         0      12     1000
15:        A             4 2019-01-12 07:42:00         0      13     1000
16:        A             4 2019-01-20 16:15:00         0      14     1000
17:        A             4 2019-01-28 10:41:00         0      15     1000
18:        A             4 2019-02-03 16:30:00         1      16        2
19:        A             4 2019-02-04 17:14:00         1      16        2
20:        B             1 2015-12-24 06:21:00         1      16        1
21:        B             1 2015-12-29 17:41:00         1      17        2
22:        B             1 2015-12-29 23:33:00         1      17        2
23:        B             1 2015-12-30 05:17:00         1      17        2
24:        B             1 2015-12-30 17:23:00         1      17        2
25:        B             1 2015-12-31 05:29:00         1      17        2
26:        B             1 2015-12-31 11:35:00         1      17        2
27:        B             1 2015-12-31 23:40:00         1      17        2
28:        B             1 2016-02-09 10:53:00         0      18     1000
29:        B             1 2016-03-03 15:23:00         1      19        3
30:        B             1 2016-03-03 17:37:00         1      19        3
31:        B             1 2016-03-03 21:33:00         1      19        3
32:        B             1 2016-03-04 03:17:00         1      19        3
33:        B             2 2017-01-07 13:16:00         1      20        1
34:        B             2 2017-01-07 22:24:00         1      20        1
35:        B             2 2017-01-08 06:34:00         1      20        1
36:        B             2 2017-01-08 11:42:00         1      20        1
37:        B             2 2017-01-08 20:50:00         1      20        1
38:        B             2 2017-01-31 11:39:00         1      21        2
39:        B             2 2017-01-31 16:45:00         1      21        2
40:        B             2 2017-01-31 22:53:00         1      21        2
    SITENAME SAMPLING.YEAR       DATE     TIME flow.type cluster group.ID
```

Comment: Thank you @ekoam! I’ll try this in the morning and let you know. Really appreciate your help!